# Check in javascript code if object from session is exist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In View.cshtml I have a section where I check if in session exists object named Reservation

```
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if ( @Session["Reservation"] ) 
            {
                $('.reservationDetails :input').attr("disabled", false));
                $('#termSection :input').attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

When the first time page is loaded button with id termSection is active,
but when in other action I save object Reservation in session this button still is active then I redirects to View.cshtml. I think the problem lies in this condition to check if Object from sesssion is null.

Comment: Side note: .attr should be .prop. Read http://api.jquery.com/prop/: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method."

Comment: what does `@Session["Reservation"]` actually render on the page? (Check the generated page source in your browser, it will have put some static text into the JS code). Does it result in something that JS could reliably interpret as true/false in order to evaluate the `if` correctly (bearing in mind Javascript's fairly lax attitude to truthyness)? If not then that might be where your problem lies.

Comment: @Session["Reservation"] is created and modified in methods in controller only, in JS I want only check if it is null. In other place I have checked attr(). method and it worked.

Comment: In page source in browser it shows me Repository is not defined                          if ( Repository.ViewModels.NewReservation ) 
            {
                $('.reservationDetails :input').prop("disabled", false);
                $('#termSection :input').prop("disabled", true);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you move the if condition to the server side. If the reservation isn't present, just don't render the Javascript at all.

So, instead of

```
if ( @Session["Reservation"] )
```

Use

```
@if ( Session["Reservation"] != null )
```

In context:

```
@if ( Session["Reservation"] != null )
{
     $('.reservationDetails :input').attr("disabled", false));
     $('#termSection :input').attr("disabled", true);
}
```

If `Reservation` is not null, the output Javascript will be:

```
$(function () {
    $('.reservationDetails :input').attr("disabled", false));
    $('#termSection :input').attr("disabled", true);
}
```

If `Reservation` is null, the output Javascript will be:

```
$(function () {
}
```

In other words, it won't do anything, which seems to be the intention.